# What kind of failover system do Airbuses with side sticks have?

Tags: flight-controls, airbus

Airbuses use joystick-style side sticks for controlling the aircraft. Among the features of this system is that there exists no mechanical connection between the joysticks and the control surfaces.

In case of an electrical failure, what backup system is in place to make sure the pilot still has control of the aircraft?

Comment: I read somewhere there are mechanical links for elevator trim and vertical stabilizer allowing minimum control the time the ram air turbine is deployed. I don't know if those control still exist on more recent fly-by-wire aircraft, but if not it means the fly-by-wire system is more reliable than mechanical controls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of a *total* electrical failure, the aircraft can still be controlled using rudder pedals and manual pitch trim.

The airbus EFCS (Electronic flight control systems) are configured as below:

[image: A320 EFCS]

Airbus EFCS; Image from [smartcockpit.com](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&ved=0ahUKEwjz0ZfIyNXPAhUESI8KHai1C6Q4ChAWCCEwAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.smartcockpit.com%2Fdownload.php%3Fpath%3Ddocs%2F%26file%3DA319-320-321_Flight_Deck_and_Systems_Briefing_for_Pilots.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFQsYJaJjXM76PNgoYnADcdftpO2w&bvm=bv.135475266,d.c2I&cad=rja)

From [Airbus Flight Control Laws](http://www.airbusdriver.net/airbus_fltlaws.htm):

> MECHANICAL BACKUP
>
> In case of a complete loss of electrical flight control signals, the aircraft can be temporarily controlled by mechanical mode.
>
> - Pitch control is achieved through the horizontal stabilizer by using the manual trim wheel.
> - Lateral control is accomplished using the rudder pedals.
> - Both controls require hydraulic power.

The A340 also seems to have a similar system. From the [A340 Flight Deck and Systems Briefing for Pilots](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A340_Flight_Deck_and_Systems_Briefing_For_Pilots.html):

> **Mechanical back-up**
>
> • To sustain the aircraft during a temporary complete loss of electrical power.
>
> • Longitudinal control of  the aircraft  through trim  wheel. Elevators kept at  zero deflection.
>
> • Lateral control from pedals. Roll damping is provided by the Back up Yaw Damper Unit (BYDU).

[image: A340 backup]

A340 mechanical Backup system; image from [A340 Flight Deck and Systems Briefing for Pilots](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A340_Flight_Deck_and_Systems_Briefing_For_Pilots.html)

Note that this is given only as a temporary measure. Also, See [How are fly-by-wire airliners controlled in case of complete electrical failure?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20963/how-are-fly-by-wire-airliners-controlled-in-case-of-complete-electrical-failure) and [How does the Airbus flight computer's voting system work?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15234/how-does-the-airbus-flight-computers-voting-system-work)

Comment: Do you want to add anything about using differential thrust as well?  There was an accident ([United Flight 232](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_232)) some years ago due to a hydraulic failure where the pilots used differential thrust to safely (if roughly) land in a field.  The fact that anyone survived (over half of the people on board survived) is a testament to getting the most out of the bad situation, per the NTSB.

Comment: I wonder if a full electrical failure is in any FBW training curriculum... Rudder pedals and trim wheel control sounds like "make the lawyers happy" but I'm not so sure if its successful real-world outcome.

Comment: Well in the event of a total electrical failure, you would - I think - lose engine control as most, if not all, modern airliners use FADEC engine controllers with no mechanical throttle control.  That's why they have multiple electrical buses which can be cross fed and powered by an alternator on each engine, the APU, and finally the emergency RAT.  A failure of all of those systems is less probable than damage to mechanical or hydraulic controls rendering them non functional.

Comment: @CarloFelicione -- the FADECs have dedicated engine driven PMGs for backup power

Comment: @RonBeyer -- it'd be quite annoying to fly, but the Airbus test pilots did it.

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject Test pilots yes, but what I was saying is your everyday Airbus pilot. Technically you can control a Cessna 172 the same way, trim wheel for pitch and rudder for roll/yaw if one of your control wires snapped, but nobody trains for that.

Comment: @RonBeyer -- that'd be a *very* good mainsite question -- "how far do Airbus pilots train for mechanical backup control?"

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject If you feel you can make a good question out of that, go for it, don't think I can put that together myself in the next few days.

Comment: @RonBeyer -- [asked](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32327/how-much-do-airbus-pilots-train-for-using-the-mechanical-backup-control-system) :)

Comment: @RonBeyer, I did, and it's even fun, as long as there is no _real_ emergency :) But more importantly, Cessna manual has specific instructions for this situation, so technically it's a 'design case'. (For Cessna, you normally trim for a slow speed and then control pitch/altitude with thrust; only touchdown requires re-trim).

Comment: @Zeus Its not just a "design case" its a regulatory requirement. I'll have to dig for the CFR but it basically says that there has to be at least one method of control after the primary method fails.